# How to force Terragrunt fail on first error during run-all apply execution

Tags: terragrunt

Currently when I ran terragrunt run-all apply agaings folder execution continues even if errors apppears, this cause errors in other modules so I end up with huge log output and have to search accross it for first incident.

Is there are any way to force Terragrunt fail fast?